# How can I use the typings file

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm working on a React application in conjunction with react-testing-library. In the project I've got a specific function which I would like to check the type on:

```
const customRender: any = (ui: any, options?: any) =>
  render(ui, { wrapper: AllTheProviders, ...options });
```

I've found a typings file from Definitely Typed: [testing-library__react/index.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/testing-library__react/index.d.ts)

Now I'm reading through the handbook but I can't find how to apply that interface to my function. More specifically the [consumption page in the handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/consumption.html).

I've installed the type file to my project.(`package.json, "@types/testing-library__react": "^9.1.2",`) and it states that when installing a type, you will just be able to use the project 'with no fuss'.

But how can I make use of the typings so that I can remove the `any` types in the customRender function?

Can someone point me in the right location?

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

---

Edit: Almost have it working. However it still seems to have an issue.

```js
interface CustomRenderParams<Q extends Queries> {
  ui: React.ReactElement,
  options?: RenderOptions<Q>
}

const customRender = ({ui, options}: CustomRenderParams): RenderResult =>
  render(ui, { wrapper: AllTheProviders, ...options });
```

error: `TS2314: Generic type 'CustomRenderParams<Q>' requires 1 type argument(s).`

Comment: The `tsconfig.json` file is important. Can you post yours? Or even a link to the github project your working on?

Comment: Sure! Added the tsconfig. And you can find the Github project here: https://github.com/StudioSpindle/w-playground

Comment: const customRender<Q> = ({ui, options}: CustomRenderParams<Q>): RenderResult =>
  render(ui, { wrapper: AllTheProviders, ...options });

Comment: doesn't work. TS7005: Variable 'customRender' implicitly has an 'any' type. Introduces some other errors as well.

Comment: Ok, then `const customRender<Q extends Queries> = ...`

Comment: Doesn't work either. However, this seems to work: `const customRender = (ui: React.ReactElement, options?:RenderOptions<Queries>): RenderResult =>
  render(ui, { wrapper: AllTheProviders, ...options });`

Answer (score 1):

If you open a file `node_modules/@types/testing-library__react/index.d.ts` you'll see that `render` function defined as:

```
export function render(ui: React.ReactElement, options?: Omit<RenderOptions, 'queries'>): RenderResult;
export function render<Q extends Queries>(ui: React.ReactElement, options: RenderOptions<Q>): RenderResult<Q>;
```

So you can import and reuse some types from there:

```
import {render, RenderOptions, Queries} from "@testing-library/react"

function customRender<Q extends Queries>(ui: React.ReactElement, options?: RenderOptions<Q>) {
  return render(ui, { wrapper: AllTheProviders, ...options })
}
```

Comment: Still experiencing some problems. Tried the code you provided but that does not work since it's not an arrow function. Added the latest finding to the question.